# How to create Restify request or response object from native node raw request and object

Tags: node.js, express, restify, hapi

I am building a Web application using Hapi JS. In my application I am using a library which is using the Restify version of request and response objects and I need to pass those values as parameters to one of the functions of the library.

I can retrieve the raw node request and response objects from `request.raw` object as mentioned here, https://hapi.dev/api/?v=21.0.0-beta.1#-requestraw.

But the thing is that the native node `req` and `res` objects are missing the features that Restify has. For example, `res.send`, `res.body`, etc.

Also creating own version of request for Hapi overwriting those functions might take forever because in the framework, the request is keeping track of server/ app instance and modifying the same instance of the Prototype of native request object as it is going through the request life-cycle.

How can I convert the native node `req` and `res` objects to Restify `req` and `res` objects?